# Eclipse Nsight CDT plugin pressing F3 to Open Declaration goes to the wrong line

Tags: eclipse, cuda, eclipse-cdt, nsight

Nsight Eclipse Edition

Version: 5.5.0

CDT version: 8.1.2.nvidia-qualifier

Quick reference upon mouse over pops up the wrong declaration. Usually it's a function, which is located at the same header file, as the one I'm looking for, but it has no relation to it so far. For example:

For `cudaMemcpy()` it shows me this function from `"cuda_runtime_api.h"`:

```
extern __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaPointerGetAttributes(struct cudaPointerAttributes *attributes, void *ptr);
```

For `cudaMalloc()` it gives me the description of:

```
extern __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaMemcpy2DToArray(struct cudaArray *dst, size_t wOffset, size_t hOffset, const void *src, size_t spitch, size_t width, size_t height, enum cudaMemcpyKind kind);
```

Why is indexing behaving this way? I'm getting tired of it after a couple of days working, but still couldn't find any obvious solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I will log this issue in our issue tracker. Sorry for the inconvenience. There is no workaround available.

Note that for performance reasons, Nsight does not index those files on your system. Instead, it comes prepackaged with compiled index files - apparently some headers might be different from the versions Nsight index was built from.

Comment: So, as a workaround in my particular case seems like I have to update some headers. Hence I'd like to know what info (files, versions etc.) should I provide you with so you can help me to reach consistency atm?

Comment: Unfortunately, most likely the headers used for generating the index were not released publicly. Scripts for regenerating index files are also not available publicly...

Comment: Ok, should I just wait for a new release of CUDA Toolkit? How do I catch up with the upcoming updates timely?